# numpy inline editing element

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

is it possible to edit *one* element of a numpy array and then return the array in one statement?

If, for example, I would want to do this(and I know that this *can* be done in other, more efficient and suitable ways, but this is an example):

```
arr = []
for x in range(5):
    a = np.zeros((5, 1))
    a[x, 0] += 1
    arr.append(a)
```

in one line, I would use a list comprehension, but neither `a.itemset(0, 1)` nor `a[0, 0] += 1` return `a`

The listcomp which does not work because `np.ndarray.itemset()` doesn't return anything:

```
arr = [np.zeros((20, 1)).itemset(i, 1.) for i in range(5)]
```

This would be useful in many more applications than just listcomps because it would make some code more readable and straghtforward.

Thanks for your time,
JAG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it:

```
def setret(arr, idx, val):
    arr[idx] = val
    return arr
```

Now you can write the concise/confusing code you want:

```
[setret(np.zeros((20, 1)), i, 1) for i in range(5)]
```